# Infinite PaintEvent Loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an empty paint event which sometimes begins to loop infinitely. I am not sure why. I allow the user to click buttons to input an expression. Once the user clicks confirm, I then start to simplify the expression they input as the program I am completing is a boolean algebra simplifier. Once clicked is confirmed, some subroutines are called and some validation is done. The validations are done in the form of conditional statements such as if and else and if the expression is invalid a messagebox is shown, else the simplification begins. I have shown the confirm button click event and the infinitely looping paint event below. I am unsure as to why it sometime loops infinitely and as to why it sometimes works. An example of when it infinitely loops is when the first character in the expression is a '(' but it has no nots over it.

Confirm Btn Click Event:

```
    private void ConfirmBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = "";
            char C = Expression.Text[Expression.Text.Length - 1];
            if (!IsBalanced(Expression.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Expression. Sort out brackets", "Error!");
            }
            else if (C == '⊕' || C == '•' || C == '+')
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Expression. Cannot end on an operator", "Error!");
            }
            else if (UnconnectedOperatorErrorPresent(Expression.Text, NOTs))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An operator cannot have more Nots over it than any of its adjacent variables.", "Error!");
            }
            else if (UnconnectedBracketError(Expression.Text, NOTs))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("A bracket cannot have more Nots over it than any of its adjacent variables.", "Error!");
            }
            else if (Expression.Text[0] == '(')
            {
                if (NOTs[0] > 0)
                {
                        MessageBox.Show("A bracket at the beginning of the expression cannot have NOTs over it.", "Error!");
                }
            }
            else if (Expression.Text[Expression.Text.Length - 1] == ')')
            {
                if (NOTs[Expression.Text.Length - 1] > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("A bracket at the end of the expression cannot have NOTs over it.", "Error!");
                }
            }
            else if (Expression.Text.Length > 20)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Expression has a maximum length of 20 characters.", "Error!");
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < overLines.Length; i++)
                {
                    overLines[i].Text = "";
                }
                int n = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < NOTs.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (n < NOTs[i])
                    {
                        n = NOTs[i];
                    }
                    for (int y = 0; y < overLines.Length; y++)
                    {
                        if (y < NOTs[i])
                        {
                            overLines[y].Text += "_";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            overLines[y].Text += " ";
                        }

                    }
                }
                Subroutines m = new Subroutines();
                m.ExpressionLocation(n, Expression, 311, 132);
                SimplifiedExpression = Simplify();
                if (SimplifiedExpression == "0")
                {
                    SimplifiedExpression = "0 or False";
                    NOTsNew.Clear();
                }
                if (SimplifiedExpression == "1")
                {
                    SimplifiedExpression = "1 or True";
                    NOTsNew.Clear();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < NOTsNew.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i > SimplifiedExpression.Length)
                    {
                        NOTsNew.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }

                SimplifiedExpressionForm SEF = new SimplifiedExpressionForm(Expression, NOTsNew, SimplifiedExpression);
                SEF.Show();
                ResetVariables();

            }
        }
```

The buttons and the label which outputs the expression is on top of the panel. 
Here is the paint event:

```
            private void BackgroundPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {

            }
```

I think that instead of having an else if and then an if within it, an else if with the intial condition and the condition within the if inside it would be better for example, this:

```
        else if (Expression.Text[0] == '(' && NOTs[0] > 0)
        {
               MessageBox.Show("A bracket at the beginning of the expression cannot have NOTs over it.", "Error!");

        }
```

instead of:

```
        else if (Expression.Text[0] == '(')
        {
            if (NOTs[0] > 0)
            {
                    MessageBox.Show("A bracket at the beginning of the expression cannot have NOTs over it.", "Error!");
            }
        }
```

But why would the if within the else if not work/ result in a paint event which infinitely loops?

Comment: How do you know the paint event is looping?

Comment: What happens if you delete that empty event method?

Comment: @LarsTech I used a breakpoint to observe what was happening when my program seemed to freeze.

Comment: @RufusL The code displays an error.

Comment: Presumably the error is related to some reference to the event. Can you also delete the reference, or is it some other error?